# Callback Functions on Editable Shapes (Plotly-Dash)

Tags: plotly, data-visualization, data-science, plotly-dash

I have a histogram of a model prediction's from a binary classifier.  [image]

The vertical line is a movable shape that indicates a decision threshold that I would like to analyze (made editable via the config parameter when creating dcc.Graph.)

```
dcc.Graph(id='llr-histogram',
                  config={
                    'editable': True,
                    'edits': {
                        'shapePosition': True
                    }
            })
```

Ideally, the x position of this shape would run as an Input through a callback function that is executed whenever the user moves the red line.  I'm wondering if there was an easy way in dash to do this or perhaps a better way to go about the idea.

Answer (score 0):

In Dash I think the best approach to this would be to add a slider component under the graph: [Dash Slider](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/slider)

Link the slider callback to the decision threshold and redraw the chart. Better yet you could use a slider and a button to update the chart once set

Comment: Hey Tom, thanks for answering.  Yeah, I've seen this done before.  It kind of looks ugly imo, and I was hoping that it would be possible to just directly drag around the threshold.  I guess Dash doesn't make this very easy, though

Comment: Yes that's right. I don't know of another way to do this in Dash without writing React code. In my experience the easiest approach is to always use the existing Dash components but as you say it doesn't always necessarily achieve the look you want